# How to get more than one result in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I am using XQuery to count occurrences of appearance related comments, on a thread on Social Media. However, I want to count them according to the gender of the commenters.

So far I have got XQuery to count all the occurrences of appearance comments made by females by using this:

```
for $t in doc ("women.xml") 
return count ($t/thread/comment[@gender="female]/appearance)
```

However I need some help working out how I would adapt this count the occurrences of when appearance comments are made by both men and women, simultaneously. So the count for women, and then the count for men.

I have been working on this code:

```
let $sex := ("female", "male")
for $t in doc ("women.xml")
return count($t/thread/comment[@gender=$sex[$1]]/appearance)
```

and found that it returns the count for female, if [@gender=$sex[$1]], and returns the count for male if [@gender=$s[$2]], but I was wondering if there was a way that I could adapt this so the count for both of them was printed in the output, at the same time.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest your for loops:

```
for $sex in ("female", "male")
for $t in doc ("women.xml")
return count($t/thread/comment[@gender=$sex]/appearance)
```